# Adding cherry-picked nodes to a list

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

On a project I'm working on, we'd like to give users the ability to search for nodes via a View with exposed fields, and then have them able to select specific nodes to be added to a list.

We've thought about doing this via taxonomy terms and Views Bulk Operations, but that's not very streamlined (I'd have to set the action to "Modify entity data," selecting the taxonomy field -- but then there'd be a bunch of options on the next page and the default behaviour is to overwrite all the terms attached to a node.).

Any ideas how one can create a simple cherry-picked list, ideally from Views result content?

Answer (score 0):

We have done this using the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module:

> Flag is a flexible flagging system that is completely customizable by
>   the administrator. Using this module, the site administrator can
>   provide any number of flags for nodes, comments, users, and any other
>   type of entity. Some possibilities include bookmarks, marking
>   important, friends, or flag as offensive. With extensive views
>   integration, you can create custom lists of popular content or keep
>   tabs on important content.

Make a flag and add it to your content type.  You may be able to use one of the default flags.

Configure the flag to appear on just teasers.

In your view, configure it for node output, and choose teasers and show links.  I think you can add the flag as a "field" in field-based output, but I don't remember.

Then, your view should show your list of nodes and each will have a flag link with it.  Users can flag their nodes.

You can then make views over the nodes that your users have flagged, either all together or per user.  The Flag module integrates very nicely with Views.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea, but it seems that's more conducive to creating *a* list, and not lists on-the-fly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ah, I didn't interpret your question as needing to add to a particular list.  We did this on a site over the summer.  We did the flag thing to allow users to save nodes to their favorites list.  We then made a tool to allow them to go through their favorites, and add them to particular lists, manage the list, etc.  In this situation, the list was a node and the relation was done with noderefs.